# How do i login to my account?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Here is my code. But, it does not work properly, once i login using username and password is shows error message like this:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\lumbiniinternational_hotel\administrator\login.php on line 26

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\lumbiniinternational_hotel\administrator\login.php on line 27
```

My full Code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password='".$_POST['password']."' AND role='administrator'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        header("Location:index.php");
        $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
    }else
        $message=get_word($lang,"Wrong username or password.");
}
?>
```

Comment: I think while loop is missing here as in following:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/692282/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-to-be-resour https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111015015949AAXmj7U

Comment: **Before you post a question asking “How do I solve this error?" do a search in the search box for the actual error message.**  There you will probably find other questions from people who have had the exact same problem, and then you can learn how they solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both errors show that your query is wrong.
Make sure you have spelled field names correctly.
Enclose table name and field name with ` like this:

```
select `field_name` from `table_name`
```

Change your

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

with

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will show you the proper sql error

Finally as a side note:
 - stop using  mysql extensions and switch to mysqli_ or PDO.
 - sanitize your POST data before using it directly into your query

Answer (score 0):

Check if the query goes wrong, add a `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of mysql_query

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password='".$_POST['password']."' AND role='administrator'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        header("Location:index.php");
        $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
    }else
        $message=get_word($lang,"Wrong username or password.");
}
```

In addition, I advise you to use directly `mysql_fetch_assoc` and not `mysql_fetch_array`

Mirko

Comment: mirko, your Code says: No database selected!!

Comment: Because you need to connect to an Database. Use `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`